# install kamailio packages

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-netbook

I wanna install kamailio packages on Ubuntu 11.10. I've found a tutorial for installing kamailio but I'm facing problems installing packages after adding the repository lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and using:

```
apt-get install kamailio kamailio-mysql-modules kamailio-tls-modules
```

The following message appear:

```
E: Unable to locate package kamailio
E: Unable to locate package kamailio-mysql-modules    
E: Unable to locate package kamailio-tls-modules
```

this is the link for the 
[tutorial](http://kb.asipto.com/kamailio%3askype-like-service-in-less-than-one-hour)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The packages in Kamailio's APT repository are for LTS versions of Ubuntu, at this time 10.04 Lucid and 12.04 Precise, details are at:

http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/packages/debs

Answer (score 1):

you must update repository after adding the repository lines to /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

then install kamailio

```
apt-get install kamailio kamailio-mysql-modules kamailio-tls-modules
```